# Unable to load package xlsx in R language

Tags: r

I am getting the following error while trying to load xlsx package.

> library(xlsx)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Can any one please help me with this. I am stuck in this since last two days.

After I installed the package it was installed in user library. I pasted the same at the R library location so that it might take the package from that location but it dint worked.

> library(xlsx)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Comment: There appear to be several open issues with this package related to Java. See https://github.com/colearendt/xlsx/issues

Comment: "Open issues", perhaps, but none of them include `JAVA_HOME`; there are three closed issues that do, but none of them seem to be about this error. @markhogue, are you certain that this issue is a known-thing with `xlsx`? If so, please link to is specifically.

Comment: Other than that, if you search (google or other engines) for `R xlsx rJava JAVA_HOME`, you'll find many references off of StackOverflow. Within SO, if you search for `[r] rjava java_home`, you will find many answered questions about this issue, and they all revolve around mis-installation of java and/or inability to find the system-installed java.

Comment: @r2evans I had nothing specific. Deferring to your better comment.